# SelectionChanged event on ComboBox create dynamically

Tags: c#, events, combobox, selectionchanged

In my application I have 2 `ComboBox`. When I select a `ComboBoxItem` in the first ComboBox the second one generates the relative ComboBoxItem. But if I create a `SelectionChanged` event on the second ComboBox I get this error. Why? Thanks!

```
private void scarpeBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)combo.SelectedItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        if (combo.Items[i] == item) id = i;
}
```

[image: InvalidCastException]

Comment: can you please copy past code of selectionchanged so I can edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SelectedItem` is of value `String`, it's not a control like you thought it would be. You're trying to convert your `String` to a `ComboboxItem`, which throws your exception.

In your example, I would use the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
private void scarpeBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    id = combo.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Your loop seems to look for the position of your `SelectedItem`, so replace your code with above, and it will return the position of the item in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Work!